# Simplifying XGBoost

Tags: python, references, boosting

I need to explain the concept behind XGBoost to a few people. Although I understand how it works, I'm looking for a good analogy using which I can easily describe XGBoost. Probably something which consists of analogies of decision trees, random forest classifiers, boosting algorithms, etc.

What are some good resources where I can find a simple explanation/analogy to educate my audience?

Comment: Explain _boost_, then _gradient_, then _extreme_.